# What's wrong with Satanichia's snapping a chopstick?

Tags: gabriel-dropout

In *Gabriel DropOut*, there is [a scene](https://youtu.be/gaejP1Mq_oc?t=35) where Satanichia snaps her chopstick, then Gabriel makes some comment and Satanichia gets mad. What's wrong with Satanichia's snapping a disposable chopstick?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The joke is that Satania snapped the chopsticks *incorrectly*, even if they have *an apparent shape.***

This is an example of [割り箸](https://jisho.org/word/%E5%89%B2%E3%82%8A%E7%AE%B8) (*waribashi*, lit. "splitting chopsticks")

[image: an image of wooden disposable chopsticks not yet snapped, with a crack along the chopsticks as a snapping point]

<sup>Image courtesy of [kufura - もらって使わなかった「割り箸」みんなは何に使ってる？様々な用途が集まりました](https://kufura.jp/life/cost/160653)</sup>

And this is the expected usage

[image: an image of a hand holding an already snapped chopsticks]

<sup>Image courtesy of [mybest - 【2022年】割り箸のおすすめ人気ランキング25選](https://my-best.com/4740)</sup>

Not this

[image: an image of a boy breaking chopsticks in half]

<sup>Image courtesy of [イラストフリー素材タカヲ's - 怒って割り箸を折る子供（男の子）のイラスト](https://takawos.com/broken_disposable_chopsticks_angry-boy/)</sup>

Comment: Is it even possible to split a piece of wood along its length?

Comment: @Michael yes, I also tried it while writing this answer, and it didn't need that much strength to split along its length.